# Cache objects for onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a reason to cache `myId` like below (let's say the object `myId` will only be used for this popup function, nowhere else in the JavaScript).

```
var myId = document.getElementById('myId');
myId.onclick = function () {
  alert('button was clicked');
}
```

I figure that the `onclick` event will only be set once and that it is unnecessary. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason to cache would be if you would want to use the `myid` *element*  for **more than just binding the click event**.

One often caches elements for just that reason, which saves performance because you dont have to search the DOM tree more than once.

Answer (score 0):

It's often a good idea to cache the element for the one more time you may end up using it, but there is no reason you would HAVE to save it for later if you were sure you wouldn't need to access it again.

Answer (score 0):

You're just assigning a variable that could possibly conflict with another down the track. If you're only setting the callback once, just do it like this:

```
document.getElementById('myId').onclick = function () {
    alert('button was clicked');
}
```